# Считать на сервере параметр post - запроса

Tags: python, сервер, http, post, requests

Пишу простенький http сервер на python используя библиотеки `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` и `HTTPServer` и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно в пост запросе передать атрибут, который определяет поведение на сервере. То есть например при переданном атрибуте 1, данные записываются в базу1, а при переданном атрибуте2, данные записываются в базу2.

**Я пытаюсь это реализовать при помощи параметров data, и params, при передаче запроса.**

```
res = requests.post(url, data = "aaa", params = 1)
```

**Параметр data у меня считать получилось при помощи такого выражения:**

```
content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
```

**Код функции:**

```
def do_POST(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
```

**Как считать данные из params???**

Comment: @CrazyElf тоже на python

Comment: @CrazyElf Поправил

Comment: @AndreyM, `params` нужно извлекать из `url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры из запроса нужно извлекать из `url`, в `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` он доступен через свойство `path`. А чтобы распарсить `url` используем функции модуля `urllib.parse`

Пример:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


class HttpProcessor(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.path)
        result = urlparse(self.path)
        print(result)
        print(parse_qs(result.query))

        length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8')
        print('post_data:', post_data)

        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("Ok!", 'utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(("localhost", 80), HttpProcessor)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Тестируем:

```
import requests

rs = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1', data='1234', params=dict(abc=123, name="Foo", value=True))
print(rs)
print(rs.content)
```

Результат на сервере:

```
/?abc=123&name=Foo&value=True
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/', params='', query='abc=123&name=Foo&value=True', fragment='')
{'abc': ['123'], 'name': ['Foo'], 'value': ['True']}
post_data: 1234
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AndreyM, пожалуйста :)